# Calling Entity's function with a derived class

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to implement a way of spawning custom entities who's class is derived from a base-class.

The file directory structure looks like this:

game/test.py
game/entities
game/entities/baseclass.py
game/entities/static_polygon/main.py

Inside of baseclass.py

```
class Entity(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def GetPos(self):
        return self.Pos

    def OnCollision(self):
        print("test")
```

static_polygon imports baseclass's Entity() class that contains a few basic functions.
It also has custom functions added to the derived class.

Inside of static_polygon/main.py

```
from baseclass_entity import Entity

self = Entity

def OnCollision(self):
    print("I did it!")
self.OnCollision = OnCollision
```

In order to create a polygon, I call Entity() and it automatically spawns a polygon but what I'm looking for is a way to call Entity("staticpolygon") and use that folder's main.py as my class.

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inheritance:

```
from baseclass_entity import Entity

class MyEntity(Entity):

    def OnCollision(self):
        print("I did it!")

my_entity = MyEntity()
my_entity.OnCollision()
```

prints:

```
I did it!
```